# Read RFID tag and display chart via HDMI

Tags: hdmi, rfid, input-device, database

I'm a beginner in Raspberry Pi developing, I'm more familiar with embedded programming. But now, I have got a project, where I definitely need the performance and GUI of an Raspberry Pi :)

## Overview

I'm organizing a birthday party where I would like to show live drinking stats () at a beamer. Something like this:

Person 1:  |  |

Person 2:  |  |

Person 3: - | - |

and so on....

## Idea

1. Every person gets a personalized RFID tag. This tag will be programmed by me before the party starts. I will use my smartphone, so there is no need to do this with the Raspberry Pi. Content: "Name = Person1"
2. The Raspberry Pi is located in the near of the drinking station. It has got 3 button inputs to select the current drink and 1 RFID reader input. There are also 1 acknowledge LED and 1 acknowledge beeper as output. Further there should be a beamer connected via HDMI to the Raspberry Pi to show the drinking stats.
3. When anyone drinks something he has to go to the Raspberry Pi, press a drink button and while pressing put the personalized tag to the Reader.
4. When the Raspberry Pi has read the tag it will acknowledge the successful read and update the drinking stats.

## Questions

1. Which OS should I use for this project?
2. Which RFID reader should I use?
3. How can I create a very easy database to save / display the stats?
4. How to show the stats in the easiest way?

Is there anywhere a sample project which is similar to this?

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: i can just see the button mashing contests of who can show more drinks than anyone else

Comment: this is a Q&A site for answering one specific technical question at a time ... it is not a brainstorming chat forum

Comment: You are asking four questions. Let me answer the first two. (1) For newbies, I would recommend the official OS, ie the Rpi OS. (2) For newbies, I would recommend the RC522 RFID reader module.